# Test RPC via Node and repeated contract calls

Tags: testrpc, nodejs

On the testrpc, I deploy a contract:

```
myContract.new(....
```

And it works great.  I get a transaction hash, a transaction reciept, and a contract created address output in the terminal.

But then I close out node (not the testrpc) and then when I restart it and run

```
web3.eth.getCode(contract_address, function(err, code) { console.log(code);})
```

I get 0x0

I'm hoping to call that contract again to run functions and call variables.  Anyone have solutions to this?

Comment: If you do not restart testrpc the contract should still be present when you restart your app. How do you save contract_address between sessions?

Comment: I'm using local files to save them.  Looking at the testrpc looks fine, but then calling them is an issue

Comment: Is contract_address correctly formatted? ie "0x12341234...". Did you check if err is non null?